# How to allocate a uiview programmatically that uiview in story board or XIB?

Tags: objective-c, dynamic, uiview, storyboard, xib

It's maybe weird quesiton. I know how to repeat a uiview using for loop

```
int x=0;
int y=0;
for(int i = 0: i < 10: i++)
{
uiview *name = [[uiview alloc] initwithframe:(x,y,10,10);
[self.view addsubview:name];
y+=10; x+=10;
}
```

But here, what I need is that uiview allocated in stroyboard or xib and it have connection like

```
IBOutlet UIView *dummyView;
```

Need to change dummyview y position (like copy past or repeat same view). Is that possible to do that in code like above code ( for loop )

```
int y=0;
for(int i = 0: i < 10: i++)
{
// need to change dummyview y position
y+=10;
}
```

Here that 10 is variable.

**Note:**
It's possible with uitableview here that dynamic dummyview is subview for tablecell I don't want to use tableview inside tablecell.

And also possible with scrollview but I don't want to waste memory, because this tableviewcell like show more option (remember uilable show more or less option). If you want to see more uiview than only it's going to repeat that view otherwise it's only one uiview.

**Update:**
I want to copy past a uiview in programmatically. UIView (subview for self.view) from xib or storyboard.
I am using autolayout.
This uiView have multiple uibutton and uilabel how can I identify that particular view and uibutton etc.,

Hope it's understandable :) .. If it's not add a comment.

Comment: I don't fully understand. Do you just want to load an XIB multiple times to add subviews?

Comment: @Wain yes like that. xib have a uiview I want to load multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean but if you want to copy multiple views,you can try this

```
int y=0;
for(int i = 0: i < 10: i++)
{
    UIView *copyOfView = (UIView*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_dummyView]];
    CGRect frame = copyOfView.frame;
    frame.origin.y = i*10;
    copyOfView.frame = frame;
    [self.view addSubView:copyOfView];
}
```

If you load UIView from .xib file you should replace:

```
UIView *copyOfView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourCustomView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Yes you are correct I want copy a uivew multiple times that uiview not from code. I am using autolayout so it's not working. :( but it's create multiple view with 0 width... and y doesn't change...

Comment: If you want to change UIview frame that you set Auto Layout, you can use 
`self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES`. But this will break other constraint. So you should add auto layout(constraint) via code this link will help [link](http://matthewmorey.com/creating-uiviews-programmatically-with-auto-layout/)

Comment: Thanks for your support, but I am already tired that link it's doesn't work for me. In for loop Y position changes effect other uiview constraints. So only I asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you will be able to reuse a view like that from the storyboard.
The correct way to achieve what you want to do will be to create a new UIView subclass with an xib.
Design it in the IB. Add all the subviews you want and attach IBOutlets.
There you have a reusable view.